# List the top 10 io usage

Tags: centos, rhel8

How can I print/capture the top 10 io usage? I'm using the `iotop -o | head -n 11` but the output keeps changing. I wanted to capture the first output after running it.

Thank you,

Comment: Top 10 of what? Processes?

Comment: Note that IO is measured over a time interval and measuring IO over a longer time interval most likely will see a different pattern of I/O usage and top users than the default short 1 second sampling.

Comment: @Turdie top 10 I/O usage for the last 5 mins.

Comment: @HBruijn how can I capture the usage for the last 5 mins? is it possible to save it to text file?

Answer (score 0):

To execute `iotop` only once you need to exec the command on this way:

```
iotop -n 1|head -n 11
```

To clear a bit of output you can try something like:

```
iotop -q -n 1|head -n 11
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. i need an non-interactive command but the result is like the interactive. thanks

Comment: @IamBayMax, add another option to the answer

Comment: can you share what option i should add?

Comment: @IamBayMax, I edited my answer, did you check it? The option is `-q`

Comment: yes but i need a non-interactive command as I will run it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

RMaaS

[`man iotop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop)

> ```
> -b, --batch
> ```
>
> Turn on non-interactive mode. Useful for logging I/O usage over time.
>
> ```
> -n NUM, --iter=NUM
> ```
>
> Set the number of iterations before quitting (never quit by default).  This is most useful in non-interactive mode.

Thus:

```
 iotop --batch -n 1  |head
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. I tried to run it but the output is kinda messy. How can I make the output like the result in interactive mode?